# How to group common values in column R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I would like to group common values in a column, and obtain sums of the corresponding values in other columns. I have the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(age = c("40-45", "40-45", "40-45", "40-45"),
                 age.cat = c("35-40", "40-45", "35-40", "40-45"),
                 x = c(21, 170, 36, 96),
                 y = c(47, 110, 121, 394),
                 desc = c("eating", "eating", "running", "running"))

  age  age.cat    x    y     desc
40-45    35-40   21   47   eating
40-45    40-45  170  110   eating
40-45    35-40   36  121  running
40-45    40-45   96  394  running
```

For every instance that `age.cat` and `age` don't match, I'd like to convert `age.cat` into `age` and condense that row by summing the values in `x` and `y`. So the output will look like:

```
  age  age.cat    x    y     desc
40-45    40-45  191  157   eating
40-45    40-45  132  515  running
```

This question is very obviously not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group), since I am also asking to retain the `age.cat` variable. Notice from the desired output that I am asking to group `age` and also retain `age.cat` when `age` is equal to `age.cat`.
How do I do this? A `tidyverse` solution is preferrable, thanks!

Comment: with this data, you could do a sum by group `df %>% summarise(across(x:y, sum), .by = c(desc, age))`

Comment: If what you need is as @Maël has said, then this issue has nothing to do with `age.cat`. The logic you describe on `age` and `age.cat` is unclear.

Comment: What @Maël proposed solves half my problem. What you can easily observe from the output desired is to group `age`, as well as retain `age.cat` when the two are equal. This should make it very clear to you.